# How would I change this select statement so that it formats as a currency with commas

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT sv.PARENTACCOUNT as 'Account Number'
, sum(case when BALANCECHANGE >0 then BALANCECHANGE else 0 end) as 'Total Credits'
, sum(case when BALANCECHANGE<0 then BALANCECHANGE else 0 end) as 'Total Debits'
```

How would I change this select statement so that it formats as a currency with commas. I would like the sums to be currency

Comment: Side-note - unless you are working exclusively in SQL Server this is a better task for your presentation layer.  Don't do this in SQL if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://database.guide/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-in-sql-server-t-sql/

```
SELECT sv.PARENTACCOUNT as 'Account Number'
, format( sum(case when BALANCECHANGE >0 then BALANCECHANGE else 0 end),'c')  as 'Total Credits'
, format(sum(case when BALANCECHANGE<0 then BALANCECHANGE else 0 end),'c')  as 'Total Debits'
```